# Почему добавляются пробелы в конец строки

Tags: c++, строки, c++11

Задание такое: в данной строке у всех слов, взять первую букву и переместить её в конец этого слова и добавить к этой букве -"ay".
Если ввести-"This is my string". То должно получиться-"hisTay siay ymay tringsay".
Но у меня, если в конце добавить один из этих знаков - "?", "!", ". ",", то в конце строки добавляются пробелы, вот так получается- `"hisTay siay ymay tringsay ?    "`
Вот мой код:

````
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

std::string pig_it(std::string str)
 {
      std::stringstream ss(str);
      std::string temp[255];
      std::string out;
      int count=0;
      std::string word;
      while(ss>>word)
      {
          if(word=="!"||word=="?"||word==","||word==".") temp[count]=word;
          else temp[count]=word.substr(1, word.size())+word[0]+"ay";
          count++;
      }
      int c=0;
      for(int i=0; i<str.size();++i)
      {
          if(str[i]!=' ')
          {
              out+=temp[c];
              i+=temp[c].size()-3;
              c++;
          }else {out+=" ";}
      }
      return out;
 }```

Не могу понять как убрать пробелы или не добавлять их вот в этом куске:
`if(word=="!"||word=="?"||word==","||word==".") temp[count]=word;`
Пробывал `word[0]` всё равно пробелы есть.
Подскажите пожалуйста?
````

Answer (score 0):

НАшёл сам.
Вот здесь
`else {out+=" ";}`
надо поставить проверку на конец слов в массиве:
`else if(c<count){out+=" ";}`